# Symfony 6, selection of three select fields (Department -> Commune -> Arrondissement)

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I was about to set up a form with Symfony 6 where the user must first select the department, then the municipality and finally the District to finish.
My problem is that I manage to correctly load the data of the municipality by choosing the department, but I'm produced to load the data of the district by selecting a department. I think the problem comes from JS.
I used an eventlister to do it but it works for the first select but nothing for the second.

**Departement Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\DepartementRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DepartementRepository::class)]
class Departement
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $codeDepartement = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'departement', targetEntity: CommuneDistrict::class)]
    private Collection $communeDistricts;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'departement', targetEntity: ZoneTravail::class)]
    private Collection $zoneTravails;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'departementResidenceID01', targetEntity: Candidat::class)]
    private Collection $candidats;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->communeDistricts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->zoneTravails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->candidats = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeDepartement(): ?int
    {
        return $this->codeDepartement;
    }

    public function setCodeDepartement(int $codeDepartement): self
    {
        $this->codeDepartement = $codeDepartement;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, CommuneDistrict>
     */
    public function getCommuneDistricts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->communeDistricts;
    }

    public function addCommuneDistrict(CommuneDistrict $communeDistrict): self
    {
        if (!$this->communeDistricts->contains($communeDistrict)) {
            $this->communeDistricts->add($communeDistrict);
            $communeDistrict->setDepartement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCommuneDistrict(CommuneDistrict $communeDistrict): self
    {
        if ($this->communeDistricts->removeElement($communeDistrict)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($communeDistrict->getDepartement() === $this) {
                $communeDistrict->setDepartement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

 

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }
}
```

Commune Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CommuneDistrictRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CommuneDistrictRepository::class)]
class CommuneDistrict
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?int $codeComDistr = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'communeDistricts')]
    private ?Departement $departement = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'CommuneDistr', targetEntity: ArrCuCr::class)]
    private Collection $arrCuCrs;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'ComDistr', targetEntity: ZoneTravail::class)]
    private Collection $zoneTravails;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'communeResidenceID02', targetEntity: Candidat::class)]
    private Collection $candidats;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->arrCuCrs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->zoneTravails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->candidats = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeComDistr(): ?int
    {
        return $this->codeComDistr;
    }

    public function setCodeComDistr(?int $codeComDistr): self
    {
        $this->codeComDistr = $codeComDistr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDepartement(): ?Departement
    {
        return $this->departement;
    }

    public function setDepartement(?Departement $departement): self
    {
        $this->departement = $departement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ArrCuCr>
     */
    public function getArrCuCrs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->arrCuCrs;
    }

    public function addArrCuCr(ArrCuCr $arrCuCr): self
    {
        if (!$this->arrCuCrs->contains($arrCuCr)) {
            $this->arrCuCrs->add($arrCuCr);
            $arrCuCr->setCommuneDistr($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeArrCuCr(ArrCuCr $arrCuCr): self
    {
        if ($this->arrCuCrs->removeElement($arrCuCr)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($arrCuCr->getCommuneDistr() === $this) {
                $arrCuCr->setCommuneDistr(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }



    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

}
```

Arrondissement Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArrCuCrRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ArrCuCrRepository::class)]
class ArrCuCr
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $code = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'arrCuCrs')]
    private ?CommuneDistrict $CommuneDistr = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'ArrCuCr', targetEntity: ZoneTravail::class)]
    private Collection $zoneTravails;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'arrondissementResidenceID03', targetEntity: Candidat::class)]
    private Collection $candidats;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->zoneTravails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->candidats = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(int $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCommuneDistr(): ?CommuneDistrict
    {
        return $this->CommuneDistr;
    }

    public function setCommuneDistr(?CommuneDistrict $CommuneDistr): self
    {
        $this->CommuneDistr = $CommuneDistr;

        return $this;
    }


    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }
}
```

My Candidat Form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\ArrCuCr;
use App\Entity\Candidat;
use App\Entity\CommuneDistrict;
use App\Entity\Departement;
use App\Entity\Langue;
use App\Entity\NiveauEtude;
use App\Entity\ZoneTravail;
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use App\Repository\DepartementRepository;
use App\Repository\CommuneDistrictRepository;
use App\Repository\ArrCuCrRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class CandidatType extends AbstractType
{
    private $countryRepository;
    private $StateRepository;
    private $stateCitiesRepository;

    public function __construct(
        DepartementRepository $countryRepository,
        CommuneDistrictRepository $stateRepository,
        ArrCuCrRepository $stateCitiesRepository
    ) {
        $this->countryRepository = $countryRepository;
        $this->StateRepository = $stateRepository;
        $this->stateCitiesRepository = $stateCitiesRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('departementResidenceID01', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => Departement::class,
                'label' => 'ID01.Dans quel département vivez-vous ?',
                'disabled' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'choice_label' => function(Departement $country) {
                    return $country->getNom();
                },
                'invalid_message' => 'Vous devez selectionner un departement',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir departement',
            ])

         ->add('communeResidenceID02', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [],
            'placeholder' => 'Choisir une commune/district',
        ])
            ->add('arrondissementResidenceID03', ChoiceType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir un arrondissement CU/CR',
            'choices' => [],
        ]);

        //**************** Start Commune Form
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Departement $sport = null) {
            $positions = null === $sport ? [] : $sport->getCommuneDistricts();

            $form->add('communeResidenceID02', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => CommuneDistrict::class,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $positions,
            ]);
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getDepartementResidenceID01());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('departementResidenceID01')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sport);
            }
        );
        //**************** End State Form

        //**************** Start Arr Form
        $formModifierArr = function (FormInterface $form, CommuneDistrict $commune = null) {
            $com = null === $commune ? [] : $commune->getArrCuCrs();

            $form->add('arrondissementResidenceID03', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => ArrCuCr::class,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $com,
            ]);
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $eventCom) use ($formModifierArr) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $eventCom->getData();
                $formModifierArr($eventCom->getForm(), $data->getCommuneResidenceID02());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('communeResidenceID02')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $ev) use ($formModifierArr) {
                $comR = $ev->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifierArr($ev->getForm()->getParent(), $comR);
            }
        );


    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Candidat::class,
            //'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the problems comes from JS, then why post everything except for the generated HTML and JS?

Comment: thank you, obviously I had noticed a 422 error in my symfony profiler. I'll check everything then